# App relaunching after pushing into background using appium's runAppInBackground(10);

Tags: java, selenium, automation, appium

I am trying to push app in background and then launch it from the same screen from where it is pushed in backgroound.

I am using the following code

```
((AppiumDriver)driver).runAppInBackground(10);
```

Also tried to set noReset from the capabilities, but did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by setting **dontStopAppOnReset** capability to true.